# Zend tool project provider creation error

Tags: zend-framework

Trying to create a provider using the ProjectProvider using the following code:

```
zf create project-provider testng actionName
```

I receive the following error:

```
No node was found to append to.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out that `zfproject.xml` doesn't have `<projectProvidersDirectory enabled="false">`
just add it to the `projectDirectory` node